# 'UIView' may not respond to 'addCurrentTile'

Tags: objective-c

I have a class called boxView.h/m and another called TileView.h/m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TileView.h"

@interface BoxView : UIView {
}
- (void) addCurrentTile: (TileView*)aTile;
@end
```

The .m file has a method in it:

```
-(void) addCurrentTile: (TileView*)aTile{
    [currentTurnTilesArray addObject:aTile];
}
```

In TileView.m I need to call addCurrentTile.  Currently this seems to work but I'm getting a warning saying that `'UIView' may not respond to 'addCurrentTile:'`

```
#import "TileView.h"
#import "BoxView.h"

@implementation TileView


- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tileflipped.png"]];
[self.superview addCurrentTile:self];

}
```

I've attempted to read and learn more about calling methods from different classes, but I can't seem to get this warning to go away.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cast:

```
[(BoxView *)self.superview addCurrentTile:self];
```